# Pandas - Looping over columns for assignment optimization

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making a program that assigns volume to providers based on their rank. The data is like this:

```
Origin  Dest    Provider    Vol_A       Vol_B       Vol_C   Capacity        rank
NYC     AMS     A           90          1300        2500        4000        1
NYC     AMS     B           150         600         1700        3000        2
NYC     BRI     A           105         700         100         2300        1
NYC     BRI     C           300         1300        200         2800        2
```

The goal is to assign all the volume to the #1 ranked provider until their `Capacity` is met. In the first example, NYC to AMS, Provider A will be assigned 240 units of `Vol_A` because 90+150 = 240. The desired output looks like this:

```
Origin  Dest    Provider    Vol_A   Vol_B   Vol_C   Capacity    rank    assg_a  assg_b  assg_c
NYC     AMS     A           90      1300    2500    4000        1       240     1900    1980
NYC     AMS     B           150     600     1700    3000        2       0       0       2220
NYC     BRI     A           105     700     100     2300        1       405     1895    0
NYC     BRI     C           300     1300    200     2800        2       0       105     300
```

In the NYC-AMS example, Provider A was not able to fill all of the `Vol_C` so some of it spilled over to Provider B.

My code is as follows:

```
def assign():
    vol_sim = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Origin','Dest','Provier','rank','Vol_E','Vol_C','Vol_U','Capacity','assg_e','assg_c','assg_u'])
    for key,lane in inputs.groupby(['Origin','Dest'])
        for col,out in zip(['Vol_E','Vol_C','Vol_U'],['assg_e','assg_c','assg_u']):
            to_assg = lane[col].sum()       
            assg = 0                        
            remain = to_assg               
            for idx,row in lane.iterrows():
                if assg >= to_assg:
                    row[out] = 0
                    row_temp = pd.DataFrame(row[['Origin','Dest','Provider','rank',col,'Capacity',out]])
                    row_temp2 = row_temp.T
                    vol_sim = vol_sim.append(row_temp2)
                else:
                    if row['Capacity'] <= to_assg:
                        row[out] = row['Capacity']
                        assg = assg + row[out]
                        remain = remain - assg
                        row_temp = pd.DataFrame(row[['Origin','Dest','Provider','rank',col,'Capacity',out]])
                        row_temp2 = row_temp.T
                        vol_sim = vol_sim.append(row_temp2)                            
                    else:
                        row[out] = remain
                        assg = assg + row[out]
                        remain = remain - assg
                        row_temp = pd.DataFrame(row[['Origin','Dest','Provider','rank',col,'Capacity',out]])
                        row_temp2 = row_temp.T
                        vol_sim = vol_sim.append(row_temp2)
    return vol_sim
```

The result I'm getting (shown below) seems to have duplicates for each iteration over the columns. I'd like my results to be in the same format as my desired output, without all the `nans`. I think I could do this by grouping the data, but I'd rather have it done within the function itself. Any ideas?

```
Origin  Dest    Provider    Vol_A   Vol_B   Vol_C   Capacity    rank    assg_a  assg_b  assg_c
NYC     AMS     A           90      1300    2500    4000        1       120     nan     nan
NYC     AMS     B           150     600     1700    3000        2       0       nan     nan
NYC     AMS     A           90      1300    2500    4000        1       nan     1900    nan
NYC     AMS     B           150     600     1700    3000        2       nan     0       nan
NYC     AMS     A           90      1300    2500    4000        1       nan     nan     1980
NYC     AMS     B           150     600     1700    3000        2       nan     nan     2220
```

Comment: I don't get how `assg_c` for the first row of the desired output becomes 1980, when the capacity is 4000, and the sum for that row (A, B, C) is 4120, and 2500+1700 is 4200.

Comment: I second @roganjosh's comment. Also, is there a priority as to which volume to take first? For instance, assuming there is spare capacity, does it matter if you take Vol_A, Vol_B or Vol_C from the shipper with the lower rank?

Comment: @roganjosh that was a typo on my part. For the first row, `assg_c` would be 1860 and the second would be 2340. So 2340+1860 = 4200, which is required for `assg_c`.

Comment: @mortysporty I'd like it to start by assigning `vol_a` first, then `vol_b` and `vol_c`. The goal is to have the higher ranked shipper take all the volume (if possible) then spill over to the other shippers if needed.